# Microsoft Excel Axis Options sidebar

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

Could I check what is the keyboard shortcut to select the various options in the Axis Options side tab?

e.g. for Bin width, the 'B' is underlined and in older excel version where axis options are in dialog boxes, you could simply type 'B' to jump to that selection.

Am asking as I have looked up various excel shortcut websites but am unable to find the correct shortcut.

Please see this for the side tab I am referring to:

[image]

Comment: No I don't think all those hotkeys would be collected anywhere.

Comment: Sorry do you mean it is not possible to use hotkeys to access fields in the sidetab?

Comment: No, obviously you can use hotkeys. I mean list of those hotkeys are not published.

Comment: @MátéJuhász would you happen to know which hotkeys those are? I think that was my original question.

Comment: Yes, that's your original question. If I have known the answer I'd have posted it already.

Answer (score 0):

It's alright I found the answer.

Just need to press F6 to toggle the focus to the side tab (task pane), then can use hotkeys as normal.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-keyboard-to-work-with-the-ribbon-954cd3f7-2f77-4983-978d-c09b20e31f0e